# How to insert date into google header using app script?

Tags: date, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Hello I am trying to set a date into Google Doc's document header. Now, here is the code I got so far but it won't change the current date inside my document's header as I close the document and re-open it any ideas what might be wrong with this code? on the document this is how I have my date: "Daily Report of: 10-19-20"

```
function onOpen() {
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");   
   var pattern = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
   var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
   header.editAsText().replaceText(pattern, date);
}
```

Also please note that I do have a date in this format inside my header: 15-10-2020. But this should update to give me today's date. However, that's not happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not happening because on your pattern you are looking for a date like `18.10.2020`

Instead of using your pattern with `.` change it to be with `-`:

```
var pattern = "\\b\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}\\b";
```

Also, I would recommend running the script from the Script editor the first time and  checking if it works, then doing it by closing and re-opening the document.

Comment: Hi friend. Thanks for the help but its just not doing anything. I am extremely confused. I will update the code in the original question. Please see above. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your document to see if there is anything different? Share it publicly without personal information

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to update the text of `15-10-2020` at the header using `var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "dd-MM-yyyy")` in Google Document using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to modify the value of `pattern` as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and test it again.

From:

```
var pattern = "\\b\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\b";
```

To:

```
var pattern = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
```

### Added:

From your updated question, it was found that your value on Google Document was `Daily Report of: 10-19-20`. In this case, how about the following modification?

From:

```
var pattern = "\\b\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\b";
```

To:

```
var pattern = "\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2,4}";
```

- By this modification, the values of `10-19-20` and `10-19-2020` can be updated.

Comment: @mrRay Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your updated question, I proposed one more modification. Could you please confirm it? I had thought that your date text is like `15-10-2020`. So I proposed the 1st modified script. I apologize for this.

Comment: But I think the problem is the pattern. The date is located inside the header and it seems like for whatever reason, its not understanding the pattern to identify the old date.

Comment: @mrRay Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, when the value of `Daily Report of: 10-19-20` is existing in the header and when the pattern of `var pattern = "\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2,4}"` is used, I can confirm that `10-19-20` is updated to `date`. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Google Document including the current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this?